# Check argument type (from a variable length argument list) at runtime in Scala

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, runtime-type

I am designing the interface for a system that can accept rules to be applied to a given data structures.

The main system is supposed to work as a driver receiving commands like "apply rule X to arguments U,V,W,...". I don't know all possible rules at compile time, so I thought to embed the argument type information on the rule definition and verify it latter.

Right now the rule definition is as follows:

```
trait Rule {
  val argTypes: Seq[Class[_]]
  def apply(stt: State, args: Seq[Any])
}
```

The number of actual arguments in `args` must match the number of type defined in `argTypes`, and the method `apply` should return an manipulate the state. (Actually, this is simplified explanation but this is the general idea).

I also implemented a function called `checkTypes` to verify if the types of the actual arguments match the type defined in `argTypes`.

```
def checkTypes(args: Seq[Any]) {
  if (argTypes.size != args.size) {
    val msg = "Number of arguments (%d) does not match expected number (%d)."
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg.format(args.size, argTypes.size))
  }
  val err = "Incompatible argument type for [%s]. Expected: %s. Found: %s."
  for (i <- 0 until argTypes.size) {
    val formalClass = argTypes(i)
    val arg = args(i)
    val actualClass = arg.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass
    if (!(formalClass isAssignableFrom actualClass)) {
      val errMsg = err.format(arg, formalClass.getName, actualClass.getName)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(errMsg)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I try to pass integer arguments (read from console or text file) the `checkTypes` procedure fails with this message: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incompatible argument type for [1]. Expected: int. Found: java.lang.Integer.`

I am converting the integer arguments with `Integer.parseInt(t).asInstanceOf[Int]` and the rule expects two arguments of type `Int`

So, are there a more effective way to check for type of arguments at runtime?

OR

How do I convert `String` to `Int` for real?

Thanks in advance.

---

As a minimum working example, this is a session in the Scala REPL that rises the exception:

```
scala> val argTypes: Seq[Class[_]] = Seq(classOf[Int], classOf[Int])
argTypes: Seq[Class[_]] = List(int, int)

scala> def checkTypes(args: Seq[Any]) {
     |   if (argTypes.size != args.size) {
     |     val msg = "Number of arguments (%d) does not match expected number (%d)."
     |     throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg.format(args.size, argTypes.size))
     |   }
     |   val err = "Incompatible argument type for [%s]. Expected: %s. Found: %s."
     |   for (i <- 0 until argTypes.size) {
     |     val formalClass = argTypes(i)
     |     val arg = args(i)
     |     val actualClass = arg.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass
     |     if (!(formalClass isAssignableFrom actualClass)) {
     |       val errMsg = err.format(arg, formalClass.getName, actualClass.getName)
     |       throw new IllegalArgumentException(errMsg)
     |     }
     |   }
     | }
checkTypes: (args: Seq[Any])Unit

scala> val args: Seq[Any] = Seq("1".toInt, "2".toInt)
args: Seq[Any] = List(1, 2)

scala> checkTypes(args)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incompatible argument type for [1]. Expected: int. Found: java.lang.Integer.
    at $anonfun$checkTypes$1.apply$mcVI$sp(<console>:20)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:78)
    at .checkTypes(<console>:14)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: @RexKerr Actually I did not know that it was possible to call `toInt` directly on a String, but even after making the change you suggested I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mismatch between the boxed type (`java.lang.Integer`) and the unboxed type (`scala.Int` == java `int`).  The actual instance is boxed, but you're testing it against the primitive classOf.

Here's an example of what happens when primitives are boxed:

```
scala> 5.getClass
res0: Class[Int] = int

scala> (5: Any)
res1: Any = 5

scala> res1.getClass
res2: Class[_] = class java.lang.Integer
```

Note that if you pattern match on `Any` and get a primitive, it will actually pick out the boxed copy and unbox it for you.

```
scala> res1 match { case i: Int => println(i); case _ => }
5
```

Since you know you *must* be boxed, given the code you wrote, you may as well just check for `Integer` instead of `Int` (that is, use `classOf[Integer]`).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am still not sure of what would be the best way to fix my problem. Change the declaration of the `argTypes` to use `classOf[Integer]` instead of `classOf[Int]`?